# Navigation links with images align to the right (Basic CSS)

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a really basic problem but I couldn't find a tutorial that helped me and nothing seems to work.

I have a navigation:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="?page=home" ><img src="img/HOME.png"/></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="?page=team" ><img src="img/TEAM.png"/></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want align the images in the link tags to the right so I get a block of images aligned to the right. float isn't working, text-align: right isn't working and right:0px; position: absolute; isn't working either.

Comment: did u try !important after float:right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `!important`.

What are you trying to right align them to? Float right. `li` and `a` tags aren't block elements text align won't work, as the `li`'s and `a`'s will only expand to the width of what ever is inside. If you want to do that, you will need to figure out how wide you want the list, and then give the li's that width... Does that make sense?

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/leereichardt/bfuu8/) should help

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the width of the `<a>` tag, the the `text-align: right` will work. If you're not already, I suggest using FireBug (or an alternative) to view the box layout on page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inheritance and the images size. Anyway the below css should work:

```
 ul li{float:right;}
```